# Proof of Liouville's Theorem

Tags: classical-mechanics, coordinate-systems, hamiltonian-formalism, phase-space, poisson-brackets

The Wikipedia article on Canonical Transformations has a section on [Liouville's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_transformation#Liouville%27s_theorem). It makes the following argument:

> $$J=\frac{\partial(\mathbf{Q},\mathbf{P})}{\partial(\mathbf{q},\mathbf{p})}$$
> The Jacobian has the ``division'' property:
> $$J=\frac{\partial(\mathbf{Q},\mathbf{P})}{\partial(\mathbf{q},\mathbf{p})} = \frac{\partial(\mathbf{Q},\mathbf{P})}{\partial(\mathbf{q},\mathbf{P})}\Big/ \frac{\partial(\mathbf{q},\mathbf{p})}{\partial(\mathbf{q},\mathbf{P})}$$
> Eliminating the repeated variable gives
> $$J= \frac{\partial(\mathbf{Q})}{\partial(\mathbf{q})}\Big/ \frac{\partial(\mathbf{p})}{\partial(\mathbf{P})}$$
> Then, the conditions derived in the section above give $J=1.$

Why is it legal to "eliminate the repeated variables?" Basically, we have shown that
$$J= \frac{\partial(\mathbf{Q})}{\partial(\mathbf{q})}\cdot \frac{\partial(\mathbf{P})}{\partial(\mathbf{p})}$$
Wouldn't applying this type of reasoning allow us to conclude
$$J=\frac{\partial(Q_1)}{\partial(q_1)} \frac{\partial(Q_2)}{\partial(q_2)} \frac{\partial(Q_3)}{\partial(q_3)} ... \frac{\partial(P_1)}{\partial(p_1)} \frac{\partial(P_2)}{\partial(p_2)} \frac{\partial(P_3)}{\partial(p_3)}?$$

That is, that the determinant is just equal to the diagonal of the entries (something not true in general).

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/554094/2451

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the linked question by Qmechanic, the expression should read
$$J= \left(\frac{\partial(\mathbf{Q})}{\partial(\mathbf{q})}\right)_P\cdot \left(\frac{\partial(\mathbf{P})}{\partial(\mathbf{p})}\right)_q$$
where the subscript indicates which variable was held constant. Applying this type of reasoning *will* lead to the equation
$$J= \frac{\partial Q_1}{\partial q_1} \frac{\partial Q_2}{\partial q_2} ... \frac{\partial P_1}{\partial p_1} \frac{\partial P_2}{\partial p_2}$$
but this is *not* equal to the product of the diagonal entries, because care needs to be taken as to which variables are held constant for each partial derivative.